# how to add description for disabled dates in multidatepicker

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I have included the datepicker and disabled a set of dates using `addDisabledDates` attribute of datepicker. I need to display a small description about why the dates are disabled in a popup when cliked or by any actions on the disabled dates. I have used rails logic for assigning a array of dates to `addDisabledDates : <%= raw @holidays %>`. `@holidays` stores the dates to be disabled. The disabled dates are for weekends and holidays.

```html
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#datePick').multiDatesPicker({
            beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
             // For disabling all "Sundays"
            dateFormat : "d/m/yy",
            maxDate : "+3m",
            minDate : "-1m",
            multidate : true,
            addDisabledDates : <%= raw @holidays %>
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: By looking at the [*multidatespicker*](https://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/) docs, there are no events available to trigger the desired behavior.

Comment: @Pavan Is there anyother way to display the description without triggering event. Just displaying the description for the whole month in html format?